# Newly discovered SQL Server Express has all databases inaccessible/offline

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008-r2

We have several remotes sites at my company and today one of the employees came to me and said their SQL reporting tool stopped working.  Up until this point I did not even know this server or database or reporting service existed!

I have RDP access to the server and can open `SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2` and the databases appear to be `SQL Server Express`.  Currently I can login to the instance with my domain admin account but every database gives me the following message when I try to expand it:

[image]
The webpage they go to for the reports gives them the following error:

```
•   An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
    o   Cannot create a connection to data source 'DNPDataSource'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
        ?   For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
```

When I try to view the SQL Server Error log I get this error:

[image]

I do not have the `sa` password.  I'm not a DBA but need to try and figure this one out, can anyone point me in a direction to start troubleshooting this?  I'm completely lost.

---

here is the ERROR.LOG

```
2013-03-27 13:14:24.34 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64) 
    Jun 11 2012 16:41:53 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

2013-03-27 13:14:24.34 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.34 Server      All rights reserved.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.34 Server      Server process ID is 9040.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.34 Server      System Manufacturer: 'Intel Corporation', System Model: 'S5520UR'.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.34 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.34 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.34 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 2428 at 3/27/2013 1:14:02 PM (local) 3/27/2013 7:14:02 PM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.34 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2013-03-27 13:14:24.37 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.37 Server      Detected 16 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.51 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.51 Server      Lock partitioning is enabled.  This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.56 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0 Active CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.62 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.69 spid7s      2 transactions rolled forward in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.69 spid7s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.69 spid7s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.78 spid7s      FILESTREAM: effective level = 0, configured level = 0, file system access share name = 'SQLEXPRESS'.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.83 spid7s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2013-03-27 13:14:24.85 spid7s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2013-03-27 13:14:24.87 spid7s      The resource database build version is 10.50.2500. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.09 spid10s     Starting up database 'model'.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.09 spid7s      Server name is 'WCCKEMAPP\SQLEXPRESS'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.21 spid10s     The tail of the log for database model is being rewritten to match the new sector size of 4096 bytes.  2560 bytes at offset 99840 in file c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf will be written.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.31 spid10s     Clearing tempdb database.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.32 spid13s     A new instance of the full-text filter daemon host process has been successfully started.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.37 spid7s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.40 Server      A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.40 Server      Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 54547].
2013-03-27 13:14:25.40 Server      Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 54547].
2013-03-27 13:14:25.40 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS ].
2013-03-27 13:14:25.40 Server      Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query ].
2013-03-27 13:14:25.40 Server      Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL Server. If you want to use a dedicated administrator connection, restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.56 spid10s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.60 spid13s     The Service Broker protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.60 spid13s     The Database Mirroring protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.61 spid13s     Service Broker manager has started.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.77 spid7s      The tail of the log for database msdb is being rewritten to match the new sector size of 4096 bytes.  2048 bytes at offset 12007424 in file c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBLog.ldf will be written.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.84 spid7s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.90 Logon       Error: 17187, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.90 Logon       SQL Server is not ready to accept new client connections. Wait a few minutes before trying again. If you have access to the error log, look for the informational message that indicates that SQL Server is ready before trying to connect again.  [CLIENT: ::1]
2013-03-27 13:14:25.90 Logon       Error: 17187, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2013-03-27 13:14:25.90 Logon       SQL Server is not ready to accept new client connections. Wait a few minutes before trying again. If you have access to the error log, look for the informational message that indicates that SQL Server is ready before trying to connect again.  [CLIENT: 172.17.0.210]
2013-03-27 13:14:26.48 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library successfully registered the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/WCCKemAPP.WCC.LOCAL:SQLEXPRESS ] for the SQL Server service. 
2013-03-27 13:14:26.48 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library successfully registered the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/WCCKemAPP.WCC.LOCAL:54547 ] for the SQL Server service. 
2013-03-27 13:14:26.48 Server      SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:14:31.04 spid51      Starting up database 'ReportServer'.
2013-03-27 13:14:31.37 spid51      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:14:31.76 spid51      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:14:32.07 spid51      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:14:32.24 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2013-03-27 13:14:32.24 Logon       Login failed for user 'drily'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.210]
2013-03-27 13:15:12.28 spid55      Starting up database 'DNP'.
2013-03-27 13:15:13.75 spid55      Starting up database 'DSS'.
2013-03-27 13:19:36.62 spid57      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:25:31.18 spid53      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLExpress'.
2013-03-27 13:25:36.38 spid53      Starting up database 'DSSDL'.
2013-03-27 13:25:38.89 spid53      Starting up database 'DSSUSERDIR'.
2013-03-27 13:25:41.26 spid53      Starting up database 'permissionsAudit'.
2013-03-27 13:25:45.00 spid53      Starting up database 'PMKemmererProduction'.
2013-03-27 13:25:48.05 spid53      Starting up database 'PMKemmererProductionTEST'.
2013-03-27 13:26:01.57 spid54      Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:26:01.58 spid54      Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2009.100.1600' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_instance_regread'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2013-03-27 13:26:52.10 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2013-03-27 13:26:52.10 Logon       Login failed for user 'WCC\baadmin'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2013-03-27 13:26:53.37 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSDL'.
2013-03-27 13:26:53.60 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSUSERDIR'.
2013-03-27 13:26:53.92 spid59      Starting up database 'QuietDose'.
2013-03-27 13:26:54.16 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLExpress'.
2013-03-27 13:26:54.36 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:26:54.66 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:26:54.89 spid59      Starting up database 'STX'.
2013-03-27 13:26:55.57 spid59      Starting up database 'Test'.
2013-03-27 13:26:55.76 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSDL'.
2013-03-27 13:26:55.91 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSUSERDIR'.
2013-03-27 13:26:56.08 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLExpress'.
2013-03-27 13:26:56.31 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:26:56.52 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:26:56.68 spid59      Starting up database 'STX'.
2013-03-27 13:26:57.24 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSDL'.
2013-03-27 13:26:57.28 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSUSERDIR'.
2013-03-27 13:26:57.45 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLExpress'.
2013-03-27 13:26:57.55 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:26:57.74 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:26:57.83 spid59      Starting up database 'STX'.
2013-03-27 13:29:36.55 spid54      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:39:36.57 spid56      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:41:59.55 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2013-03-27 13:41:59.55 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2013-03-27 13:44:07.70 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2013-03-27 13:44:07.70 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2013-03-27 13:49:36.57 spid53      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 13:59:36.57 spid54      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:09:36.56 spid53      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:15:50.50 spid54      Starting up database 'DSSDL'.
2013-03-27 14:15:50.75 spid54      Starting up database 'DSSUSERDIR'.
2013-03-27 14:15:51.92 spid54      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLExpress'.
2013-03-27 14:15:52.25 spid54      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:15:52.51 spid54      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:15:52.70 spid54      Starting up database 'STX'.
2013-03-27 14:18:02.83 spid51      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLExpress'.
2013-03-27 14:18:46.58 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2013-03-27 14:18:46.58 Logon       Login failed for user 'WCC\baadmin'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2013-03-27 14:18:47.49 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSDL'.
2013-03-27 14:18:47.70 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSUSERDIR'.
2013-03-27 14:18:47.92 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLExpress'.
2013-03-27 14:18:48.04 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:18:48.33 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:18:48.53 spid59      Starting up database 'STX'.
2013-03-27 14:18:49.12 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSDL'.
2013-03-27 14:18:49.33 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSUSERDIR'.
2013-03-27 14:18:49.44 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLExpress'.
2013-03-27 14:18:49.60 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:18:49.84 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:18:49.98 spid59      Starting up database 'STX'.
2013-03-27 14:18:50.28 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSDL'.
2013-03-27 14:18:50.39 spid59      Starting up database 'DSSUSERDIR'.
2013-03-27 14:18:50.48 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLExpress'.
2013-03-27 14:18:50.53 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:18:50.66 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:18:50.73 spid59      Starting up database 'STX'.
2013-03-27 14:19:36.54 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:19:36.93 spid59      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:29:36.55 spid53      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:39:36.57 spid54      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:49:36.57 spid53      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 14:59:36.58 spid54      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2013-03-27 15:09:36.60 spid53      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
```

### I can provide older logs too if it will be beneficial.  I'm reading those now from here.

Results from query `select name, state_desc, is_in_standby, is_cleanly_shutdown from sys.databases;`

[image]

---

Image for Kin's request

[image]

Comment: In cases like this I've logged in via the NT LOCAL AUTHORITY system which has been blogged about. This way you get local admin rights and then can add a new SA user or just look around the errors you can't, and see what you need from there:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/argenis_fernandez/archive/2011/07/10/think-your-windows-administrators-don-t-have-access-to-sql-server-2008-by-default-think-again.aspx

With this you'll have full SA rights to the system so be careful, but at least you should get the permissions you need.

Answer (score 1):

From the error log, there are failed logins, are you trying to connect using any of the below ones ?

```
Login failed for user 'drily'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.210]

Login failed for user 'WCC\baadmin'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Also, from your screenshot, the report server databases are cleanly shutdown. Do you have **auto close option turned ON** ?

If you have rights on the server, then below TSQL will help you :

```
'RESTORE DATABASE <dbname> WITH RECOVERY' or  'ALTER DATABASE <dbname> ONLINE'
```

What is the output for below SQL:

```
SELECT name, user_access_desc, is_read_only, state_desc, recovery_model_desc, is_auto_close_on, is_auto_shrink_on
FROM sys.databases;
```

**UPDATE:**

I see the problem now ... that auto_close option is turned ON for report server databases. According to BOL:

```
When set to ON, the database is shut down cleanly and its resources are freed after the last user exits. The database automatically reopens when a user tries to use the database again.

When set to OFF, the database remains open after the last user exits.
```

Refer to [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217002608/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2009/06/24/sql-server-best-practices-autoclose-should-be-off.aspx) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130401191936/http://www.sqlmag.com/blog/practical-sql-server-45/sql-server-2008-r2/worst-practice-allowing-autoclose-sql-server-databases-140493) for more detailed explanation.